# The Herbrand quotient of a valuation ring

Tags: class-field-theory

My question stems from trying to solve the following problem:

[image]

My goal is to calculate the Herbrand quotient of $\mathcal{O}_L^\times$ by hand, so only using elementary calculations in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. If I'm not mistaken it has to be equal to one (which in our lecture we showed for every cyclic extension of local fields).

I already have an idea of how $\mathcal{O}_L^\times$ and $N_G(\mathcal{O}_L^\times)$ look like but still I don't know enough to really calculate the cohomology groups. Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: Given your "My goal is to..." paragraph, did you mean $A = {\cal O}^\times_L$, and not $A= L^\times$ as you have it in the problem statement?

Comment: I mean calculating $h(\mathcal{O}_L^\times)$ would give $h(L^\times)$ since $h(L^\times) = h(\mathcal{O}_L^\times) h(\mathbb{Z}) = 2h(\mathcal{O}_L^\times)$, right?